# Set maxImageWidth for images within gridelements col using fluid_styled_content (TS)

Tags: typo3, fluid-styled-content, tx-gridelements

Defining a custom gridelement in TS one can setup the maxImageSize for an texmedia image rendered inside a col. So in a 50-50 grid one might set the max image width to 50% of the regular max.

```
columns {
  default {
    renderObj {
      10 = LOAD_REGISTER
      10.maxImageWidth = 273          
      30 = RESTORE_REGISTER
    }
  }
}
```

However this is not working using fluid_styled_content instead of css_styled_content. Anyone knows how to configure that using gridelements with fluid_styled_content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn´t work because the fluid_styled_content [textmedia](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/ContentElements/TextMedia/Index.html) element is rendering the images inside a gallery. 
If you are above Typo3 7.4 you could use the [Gallery Data Processor](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.4/Feature-67663-IntroduceDataProcessorForMediaGalleries.html)
:

```
columns {
  default {
    renderObj {
      textmedia {
        dataProcessing {
          20.maxGalleryWidth = 273
          20.maxGalleryWidthInText = 273
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```